# need help getting started on simple Eclipse wizard / plugin

Tags: swing, eclipse-plugin, swt

I have written some Java classes that do something useful.  I'd like to wrap the functionality in a simple Eclipse plugin.  Basically you'd right-click on an object, click the "launch my wizard" option and the wizard would have 3 or 4 pages of options ... next, next, next, finish.  And the useful stuff happens.

Can someone tell me where to start in building such an Eclipse plugin?  Also, I have Swing experience, can I build the UI in Swing or does it have to be SWT?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Rob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read [Eclipse Corner Tutorial](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-JFaceWizards/index.html) on creating new wizard.

If you want to implement some kind of import/export wizard, take a look at [Developing Export Wizard for Eclipse](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3an2yUzcHlX1IJ%3arobotplaysguitar.com/2006/07/03/developing-an-export-wizard-plugin-for-eclipse-i/+eclipse+export+wizard+example&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&client=safari&source=www.google.com)

Cheers,
Max